# Batch clip multiple rasters error arcpy

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, batch

I am new to arcpy. I am attempting to batch clip over 350 rasters to one the extent of one mask raster. I tried it in model builder and it wouldn't run so now I am  trying it in arcpy but I continue to get error messages.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import os
import glob
from arcpy import env
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
from arcpy.sa import *

#Sets environment
env.workspace = "E:/AlexandraOrrego/GIS_2017/RasterData/Reclass2.gdb"

mask = "E:/AlexandraOrrego/GIS_2017/Shapefiles/westus_forest"
outputDir = "E:/AlexandraOrrego/GIS_2017/RasterData/clipped.gdb"

rasList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for raster in rasList:  
    outRasterName = raster.replace("r2", "c")
    rasterObject = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(raster, mask, outRasterName)
#Saves Raster
    rasterObject.save(os.path.join(outputDir, outRasterName))
#prints once each raster layer has been clipped
    print outRasterName + " Clipped Successfully!"

 Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
TypeError: ExtractByMask() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  A key part of your question is that you get error messages, but you haven't told us what they are.  Please **[edit]** your question to include all error messages in full (including line numbers), as text (not as a picture).

Comment: What error messages? Do you actually have a spatial analyst extension available? If your mask is a shapefile it should have the extension .shp. Try use arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask instead of arcpy.gp.ExtractByMask_sa. Do your images already exist? Try setting arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True. Does your output gdb exist? Have you inputted the path and name correctly?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I edited the code to include your suggestion of using arcpy.sa but still receive an error.

Comment: Your error says the function takes **2 inputs** but you've supplied **3 parameters**. You could be looking at old code (prior to ArcGIS 10.0) where the function *did* take 3 arguments. Change the extract by mask to rasterObject = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(raster, mask) as your output is rasterObject a *return* and not a *parameter*. If @Midavalo would consider reopening this question I could post that as an answer with appropriate links.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I have reopened the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your error says the function takes **2 inputs** but you've supplied **3 parameters**. You could be looking at old code (prior to ArcGIS 10.0) where [the function](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=5765&pid=5759&topicname=Extract_by_Mask) *did* take 3 arguments.

Between v9.3 and v10.0 there is a fundamental change in the handling of rasters by spatial analyst: from version 10 the [raster object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) is a return value, not necessarily persisted to disc, where previously the output was a parameter, implicitly stated and it was the script writers' problem to clean up temporary rasters. From version 10 rasters not saved with `raster_object.save(Full_Path)` just disappear when the script finishes (so long as the script hasn't crashed!).

Change the [extract by mask](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002n000000) to `rasterObject = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(raster, mask)` as your output is `rasterObject`, a return value and not a parameter.

9.3 and prior syntax:

```
gp.ExtractByMask_sa(InRaster, InMask, OutRaster)
```

10.0 and newer syntax:

```
out_raster_object = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask (in_raster, in_mask_data)
out_raster_object.save(out_raster)
```

This is a little *gotcha* when trying to learn or implement old code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, since changing it to two argument code works great!